# Vlookup for an array of values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

ManagerEmployeeSheet

```
     A           B
1  manager    Employee
2  M1          E1
3  M1          E2
4  M1          E44
5  M1          E41
6  M1          E34
7  M2          E100
8  M2          E17
9  M2          E29 and so on
```

I am making a **dynamic dashboard** where I need the **employees under each manager to be dynamically reflected.**

DashboardSheet

```
    A                    B
1  Input Manager      M1    #basically user inputs one manager name here in this cell
2  E1
3  E2
4  E44
5  E41
6  E34
```

So when I input M1 manager in cell B1 of `DashboardSheet` , I should get all employees under him in below cells, similarly if I input any other manager , I should get all employees under that manager.  Vlookup alone will return only the first employee corresponding to the manager, but i need all employees under him.

I have read that maybe `vlookup` with `offset` can do this. But I am not sure.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change` event for your purposes. Put a macro there.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: normal macro enabled excel 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `Office365` then you can easily do that with `Filter` formula. Try below formula as per screenshot.

```
=FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9=E1)
```

[image]

If you do not have `Office365` then use `INDEX()` and `AGGREGATE()` formula together. As per my screenshot use below formula to `D2` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$9)/($A$2:$A$9=$E$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Comment: pls upvote my quiestion.........i do not know why it has been voted down.....if you think it was good. thanks

Comment: i am getting #calc! error in my sheet using this, i dont know why

Comment: Which formula are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What I started out on the assertion that what @Harun24HR can do with one formula VBA should be able to do with one line of code became the epic effort shown below. Obviously I failed. In the project's defense I point out that where you have formulas in a worksheet you should add protection to the sheet to prevent your formulas from being damaged and that adds significantly to the management effort, too.

With that said, the code below is a Worksheet_Change procedure which must be in the code module of your Dashboard sheet and responds to a change in cell B1 (*TriggerRange*). The function it calls can go with it to the same location. Adjust the 3 constants at the top of the code (a convenience @Harun can't offer because it's one of the advantages of using VBA). The point is that you can modify any or all of the 3 constants and never need to touch the rest of the code. That makes management whole a lot easier.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 083
    
    Const TriggerRange  As String = "B1"        ' cell where the change occurs
    Const MgrClm        As String = "A"         ' change to suit
    Const EmpClm        As String = "C"         ' change to suit

    
    Dim List            As Variant              ' list of employees under one manager
    Dim OutputRng       As Range                ' range to write result to
    
    With Target
        If .Address(0, 0) = TriggerRange Then
            Set OutputRng = Range(.Offset(1), Cells(.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlDown))
            ' keep one blank between the last employee and any other column content
            OutputRng.ClearContents
            List = EmployeeList(.Value, Columns(MgrClm).Column, Columns(EmpClm).Column)
            ' write to the cell below the changed cell
            Set OutputRng = .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(List))
            OutputRng.Value = Application.Transpose(List)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function EmployeeList(ByVal Crit As String, _
                              ByVal MgrClm As Long, _
                              ByVal EmpClm As Long) As Variant
    ' 083

    Dim Fun         As Variant                  ' function return array
    Dim FltMode     As Boolean                  ' Filter set by user
    Dim Rng         As Range                    ' working range
    Dim RngArea     As Range                    ' areas of the filtered range
    Dim n           As Long                     ' index to Fun
    Dim R           As Long                     ' loop counter: Rows

    With Worksheets("Employees")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .Cells.AutoFilter
            FltMode = True
        End If
        
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, EmpClm).End(xlUp))
        With Rng
            ReDim Fun(1 To .Rows.Count)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=MgrClm, Criteria1:=Crit
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0) _
                  .Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1) _
                  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)      ' omit header row
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            For Each RngArea In Rng.Areas
                With RngArea
                    For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
                        n = n + 1
                        Fun(n) = .Cells(R, EmpClm).Value
                    Next R
                End With
            Next RngArea
        End If
        If Not FltMode Then .AutoFilter
    End With

    If n = 0 Then
        n = 1
        Fun(n) = "No subordinates"
    End If
    ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To n)

    EmployeeList = Fun
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next VBA approach:

1. Copy the next `Sub` in a standard module. It will create a validation cell keeping the unique Manager names (not required, but helpful I think):

```
Sub setValidationUnique()
  Dim shM As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet, rngV As Range, dict As Object
  Dim lastRM As Long, i As Long
  
  Set shM = Worksheets("ManagerEmployeeSheet")'use here your sheet name
  Set shD = Worksheets("DashboardSheet")      'use here your sheet name
  lastRM = shM.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 2 To lastRM
    dict(shM.Range("A" & i).value) = 1
  Next i

  Set rngV = shD.Range("B1")
  With rngV.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(dict.Keys, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
  End With
  With shD.Range("A1")
    .value = "Input Manager"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With
  shD.Activate: rngV.Select
End Sub
```

2. In the worksheet "DashboardSheet" module, copy the next event:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "B1" Then Exit Sub
    Dim shM As Worksheet, arrE As Variant, k As Long
    Dim lastRM As Long, i As Long
    
    Set shM = Worksheets("ManagerEmployeeSheet")
    lastRM = shM.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    ReDim arrE(0 To lastRM)
    
    For i = 2 To lastRM
        If shM.Range("A" & i).value = Target.value Then
            arrE(k) = shM.Range("B" & i).value: k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrE(k - 1)
    Target.Parent.Range(Target.Offset(1, -1), Target.Offset(1, -1).End(xlDown)).Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(1, -1).Resize(UBound(arrE) + 1, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrE)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Take care to appropriately name the necessary sheets, or name it "ManagerEmployeeSheet" and "DashboardSheet".

Play with the validated cell ("B1"), see the result and send some feedback.